# Search with mutiple values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a search script with PHP and MySQL. Right now, I've reached something like this, but in some cases its not working very well:

```
$id = JRequest::getInt('id');
$catid = JRequest::getVar('catid');     
$console = JRequest::getVar('console'); 
$ram = JRequest::getVar('ram');

if ($ram) {
    $ram = "AND rec_ram='$ram'";
}       

if ($console) {
    $console = "AND console='$console'";
}

$array = array(
    catid => $catid,    
    console => $console,
    ram => $ram,
);

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid='$catid' $array[console] $array[ram]";
```

What are other alternatives to do this?

Sometimes values could be empty, this is why I use:

```
if ($console) {
    $console = "AND console='$console'";
}
```

but its still working bad in some cases.

Comment: What's your problem? "Still working bad" isn't a well thought problem description. Improve your question, add examples, show your table layout etc.

Comment: Also note that if getVar is simply fetching user input from a query string (as seems likely), this has a SQL injection violation in catid  and console. The negation of !ram also seems wrong. Always be sure to escape user input, e.g. using mysql_real_escape_string() for MySQL

Comment: And why you check if $ram is empty and then add it to the conditions?Should be the opposite, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation! It's very bad to put all variables just into a string.

```
<?php

    $conditions = '';

    if ($ram) {
        $conditions .= ' AND `rec_ram`="'.$ram.'"';
    }       

    if ($console) {
        $conditions .= ' AND `console`="'.$console.'"';
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `#__content` WHERE `catid`=' . $catid . $condition . ';';

?>
```

Note, that if console or rec_ram have type of int, you do not need to quote it's values.

```
<?php

    // column console is int 
    if ($console) {
        $conditions .= ' AND `console`='.$console;
    }

?>
```

Okay, here is a way to provide a correct sql structure:

```
$conditions = array();

if ($ram) {
    $conditions[] = '`rec_ram`="'.$ram.'"';
}

if ($console) {
    $conditions[] = '`console`="'.$console.'"';
}

// some other conditions...

$condition = '';
if (sizeof($conditions) > 0)
    $condition = ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `#__content`' . $condition . ';';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I forgot to explain what i meant "working bad in some cases". Sometimes catid could be empty, which will lead a query to look like this `"SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE AND console='something'"`. (Other strings may be empty too.)I want to know how to construct variables or query so it would work in some cases without certain strings. Also there gonna be more query strings.

Comment: There's something wrong here. Btw then i echo $conditions I get before "Array" before string output. e.g `Array rec_ram="423" `

Comment: There are two variables: $condition and $conditions. Do not miss.

Comment: Oh yea sorry. I've forgot to change .= to [] = Updated again

Comment: Works good now, btw i removed     $conditions[] = ' AND `console`="'.$console.'"'; AND from here, and now it works ok. thx for help

Comment: Yeah, right. I just forgot to eompletely change the previous version, sorry.